# How to build a VUE link in a method using vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm new using **VUE.JS** and I'm in love with it! I love the **vue-router** and **router-link**! They are awesome!

Now I have a table populated by data coming from axios and I would like to build a link using this data in a custom method to have the team name clickable.

Here the template:

```
  <BootstrapTable :columns="table.columns" :data="table.data" :options="table.options"></BootstrapTable>
```

Axios returns ID, name and other data used to update the table as [here](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/using-a-method-to-update-table-using-new-data/67119)

Basically, I need to update the values in my table using the axios's received data. Something like:

```
    team: '<a v-bind:href="club/'+team.id+'">'+team.team+'</a>',
```

or

```
    team: '<router-link :to="club/'+team.id+'">'+team.team+'</router-link>',
```

But obviously it dosn't works...

How can a build a link?

Comment: Do you need to dynamically add a link to your markup? Can't you just conditionally hide/show the link?

Comment: In component, I have this:          <BootstrapTable :columns="table.columns" :data="table.data" :options="table.options"></BootstrapTable> amd data is passed as data I need to create link using router-link as in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it using custom column event and formatter in columns table setting:

```
                       {
                        field: 'match',
                        title: 'Match',
                        formatter (value, row) {
                            return `<a href="/matches/${row.pos}">${value}</a>`
                        },
                        events: {
                            'click a': (e, value, row, index) => {
                               e.preventDefault();
                                this.$router.push(`/matches/${row.pos}`)
                            }
                        }
                    },
```

**Another solution**:

Just in case of JSON code having links instead of table config is adding click listener in mounted() and a  well formatted dataset in JSON HTML link:

```
   team: "<a href=\"/club/"+team.id+"\" data-to='{\"name\": \"team\",\"params\":{\"teamId\":"+ team.id+"}}'>"+ team.team+"</a> "+userCode
```

Here the listener:

```
mounted() {
        window.addEventListener('click', event => {
            let target = event.target;
            if (target && target.href && target.dataset.to) {
                event.preventDefault();
                const url = JSON.parse(target.dataset.to);
                //router.push({ name: 'user', params: { userId: '123' } })
                this.$router.push(url);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be shorter solution for your issue :

```js
 routes = [
 {
 component : 'club',
 name : 'club',
 path : '/club/:teamid'
 }
]
```

```html
 <a @click="$router.push({ name: 'club', params: { teamid: team.id}})">team.team</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I need to render the links into a custom HTML code passed by JSON (API)